# Speed up a compiled python program?

Tags: python, qt, compiler-construction, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have quite a 'heavy' python program that I would like compiled to an exe.

The program has a decent amount of imports, but using the PyQT4 framework, I load these imports whilst a splashscreen is visible.
I compile this program to a single .exe file, using pyinstaller (in cmd):

```
python %pycompile_file% --onefile --noconsole --icon=Icon.ico Script.pyw
```

However, even though the splashscreen is set to show whilst a significant amount of modules are imported (notably including sympy), and even though it shows instantly and for an adequate time frame when ran through python;
Running the produced .exe results in a serious delay before the splashscreen shows, which is only shown for a very short time before the whole program is loaded.

My suspicion is that compiling from .pyw to .exe has sped the actual 'code' up (hence why the splashscreen in shorter), but slows the actual 'beginning' of the program's execution.

How can I fix this so that the .exe does not 'start so slowly'?

(I suspect compiling to --onefile contributes greatly, but I need the .exe file to be one folder up from all the .dlls and I can not figure out how to make pyinstaller do this)

Thanks!

---

Windows 7
python 2.7.2
pyinstaller
PyQt4

Comment: You *need* the EXE to be one level up from the DLLs? Why?

Comment: So it doesn't look so messy! The user must add files to a folder which must be in the same level as the .exe. God forbid they have to search through (or even see) the .dlls! I know I could do a simple work around with a second executable, but surely pyinstaller would allow you to do this!

Comment: Why must the user add files to the same directory as the EXE? What are they?

Comment: (A large part of such extra questions as these are to try to help to solve the problem rather than your question. These questions may lead somewhere or they may not. But they're worth considering.)

Comment: The program allows pictures to be used as backgrounds for every widget. Users can make a 'scheme' of these different backgrounds, save it and share it with others with the program. To allow the 'scheme code' (a stylesheet) to be used on others computers, they must have all the pictures in this certain folder so the program can find them when making the 'scheme' 'sharable'.

Comment: Really, it's more a preference to maintain a neat program folder hierarchy.

Comment: I would think, then, that it would be nicer to have a subdirectory for those things--e.g. call it "scheme". Better yet, permit that to be in a different location, e.g. %APPDATA%\Your App\Scheme

Comment: Would not the User still have to reach the subdirectory, by worming through a horrible mountain of .dlls? >>Do you know of any compiler (compatible with PyQt4) that can create .exes that import their .dlls from a folder?

Comment: Directories are typically shown first; DLLs will be scarcely noticed by most. If you wanted to you could even have it as YourApp\bin\* and YourApp\scheme\* and point Windows shortcuts to YourApp\bin\yourapp.exe.

Comment: Yes, but the python code expects the 'scheme' folders to be in the same directory it's in. Infact, the spew of files created by pyinstaller and qt includes folders (ugly named ones at that).
I want the User to be able to never see a .dll!

Comment: You have control of the Python code, do you not? Change it to look in a new location.

Comment: Then I have to involve the User's computer's username into the code. I would much rather just have the .exe import the .dlls from a folder, as you can see why!

Comment: No you don't and no I can't. Use `os.environ['APPDATA']` and you've got that location sorted. Or even just have bin\ and scheme\ in the installation directory. *It's not hard at all.*

Comment: This requires my program to be installed onto the computer. I intended it to be fully portable.

This still involves editing code, where as my proposed solution could mean simple arguments passed to a compiler. Surely there's a compiler that can do it? Why can't we explore that avenue? :)

Comment: APPDATA was merely one suggestion. Putting it in a sibling directory is just as reasonable and takes just as little work. For Vista/7, APPDATA is more desirable if the program is in Program Files due to UAC protection. If you're intending it to be fully portable, I hope you're considering working with the PortableApps.com Format on that side (I happen to be a developer there). There, you would probably head towards having App\AppName and Data\scheme; a common practice is to use an environment variable to override the data location.

Comment: If you are absolute that no compiler can allow the .exe to import .dlls from a folder, then I'll resign to leaving the real 'scheme' folder with all the ugly dlls and giving the User a shortcut to the scheme folder 1 level up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved;

Do not archive the .dlls into the compiled .exe.
Keep all the files imported by the code (which you wish for the User to interact with without navigating through .dlls) one level up, and create a shortcut to the .exe that has a working directory one up from the .exe.

You can make such a shortcut using pywin32.

Answer (score 4):

Pyinstaller doesn't turn python code into native code, it just packs the python bytecode and the bytecode interpreter into a single file - once start-up overheads are out of the way, actual processing will happen at exactly the same speed.

Pyinstaller's --onefile mode will make your app slower to start up, because it has to unpack all the libraries into a temporary directory before it can load them. In the case of PyQT, these libraries are fairly large so the delay will be noticable. Using one-directory mode, so that the DLLs don't need unpacking, should be much faster.

Comment: which then begins the series of problems discussed by Chris and I